# how to delete duplicate chars in String in java

Tags: java, string

I tried to use `StringTokenizer`, but what should I use as the separator?
I have `String s="abccc"` and want to display it as `"abc"`.

```
class str {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "abccc";
        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(s, "");
        for (int i = 0; i < token.length(); i ++)
            for (int j = 0; j < token.length(); j ++)
                if ((token.charAt(i) == token.charAt(j)) {
                    // ........
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What should I use as the separator? Is this the correct method for comparing?

Comment: Consecutive duplicates, or duplicates across the entire string? Be specific.

Comment: not even consecutive.like abccc,abca,rjdfrnr.

Comment: @MadhaviTalla, you need to specify which characters you consider "duplicates" in your examples. The starting string on its own doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 1):

`StringTokenizer` class is a wrong tool here, because it produces tokens, strings of one or more characters, while you are working with individual characters.

You can easily solve this problem with two nested loops going character-by-character:

- First `for (int i ...)`loop goes from zero to the length of the string
- Make a boolean flag inside the first loop, and set it to `found = false`
- Second `for (int j ...)` loop goes from `i-1` down to zero, checking each character as it goes
- If characters of your string at positions `i` and `j` are the same, set `found = true` and break the loop
- If at the end of the second loop the `found` flag is still `false`, print the character at index `i`

Comment: It means we should convert String into char array.

Comment: @MadhaviTalla No, you don't have to - you can use `charAt(i)` to get the character without converting the string to an array. If you want to make a new string, you could use `StringBuilder` and `append`.